# Lithologic and hydrostratigraphic logs for the Deccan volcanic province, India

Tags: geology, hydrology, petrology, stratigraphy, database

I need data on depth/thickness of of different lithologic units under Deccan Volcanic Province in MP, Maharashtra and Gujarat. For this if anyone can help in providing help in obtaining well log data on lithology in aforementioned region, kindly help. The depth of more than 100 m required.

Comment: One place to start would be [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=deccan%20stratigraphic%20column). You should also check with the local [geological survey](http://www.portal.gsi.gov.in).